# A measurable function to the power of a measurable function is a measurable function under some conditions?

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

I don't know if my way of solving this problem is okey or not... I would really appreciate if someone could guide me if it is wrongly thought! Thanks in advanced! Firstly, I will put some context, and then, I will show my attempt!

**Definition:** $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm \infty\}$ is a measurable function if $[f<a]=f^{-1}((\infty,a))=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}:f(x)<a\}\in\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ (where we consider $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, as the tern $(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^{n}),\lambda)$, where $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is the $\sigma$-algebra formed by the measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $\lambda:\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\to [0,\infty)\cup \{\infty\}$ is the Lebesgue positive measure).

**Things I already know:** "Product of measurable functions is a measurable function"

**Problem:** Let $E\in\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. Prove that if $f,g:E\to \mathbb{R}$ are measurable functions such that $f(x),g(x)\geq 1$, $\forall x\in E$, then $h:E\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $h(x) = f(x)g(x)$ is also a measurable function.

**Solution:**

\begin{equation*}
 [f^g <a]=(f^g)^{-1}((-\infty,a))=\{x\in E: f(x)^{g(x)}<a\}=\{x\in E: \log(f(x)^{g(x)})<\log(a)\}=
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
 =\{x\in E: g(x)\cdot \log(f(x))<\log(a)\}=[g\cdot (\log\circ f)<\log(a)]
\end{equation*}
Let's see that $\log\circ f$ is measurable, i.e, that given $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $[\log\circ f <a]\in\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$:
$$
[\log\circ f <a]=\{x\in E: \log(f(x))<a \}
$$
There exists $b\in (0,\infty)$ such that $\log(b)=a$. Then, by the fact that $f$ is measurable:
$$
[\log\circ f <a]=[\log\circ f <\log(b)]=\{x\in E: \log(f(x))<\log(b) \}=\{x\in E:f(x)<b\}=$$
$$
=[f<b]\in\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^{n})
$$
As $\log\circ f$ is measurable and $g$ is measurable, so is their product, and then we conclude that $[f^g < a]\in\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, finishing the problem. $\blacksquare$

**Note:** We have been able to "take" those logarithms by the hypothesis that $f,g$ are greater or equal than $0$.

Comment: $\log f(x)^{g(x)}=g(x)\log f(x)$ is measurable. If $\log h(x)$ is measurable then so is $h(x)$.